# Using T-SQL or C#, how can I determine the position and length of all substrings in a string?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, cobol

Given the following string (ignore double quotes):

`"I101G2.2 OZ  001 0002200 L       Y        0010000                     "`

I need to find the starting position of each substring and it's length.  For example, using the string above, the first substring is I101G2.2
starts at position 0 and is 8 characters in length. Bear in mind that each space character (" ") should be considered a substring, always one character in length. So, the output should be something like:

```
**Sub-String Value**,**Starting Position**, **Length**
I101G2.2,0,8
{space},9,1
OZ,10,2
{space},12,1
{space},13,1
001,14,3
{space},17,1
0002200,18,7
{space},25,1
L,26,1
{space},27,1
{space},28,1
{space},29,1
{space},30,1
{space},31,1
{space},32,1
{space},33,1
{space},34,1
Y,35,1
{space},36,1
{space},37,1
{space},38,1
{space},39,1
{space},40,1
{space},41,1
{space},42,1
{space},43,1
0010000,44,7
```

etc...

We have a production system written in Cobol that outputs information in the above string format.  I have a table that maps positions and string lengths to a column in another table.  So, the idea is to get the position and length of the string and compare to the mapping table to determine what table column the belongs in.  For instance
0002200 is the item class because it's at position 18, and is 7 characters in length.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the first substring starts at `0` and has `8` characters, then shouldn't the next substring start at `8`?

Comment: Hmmm..  yeah, I might have gotten the positions and lengths incorrect in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm impressed you still got Cobol running, my mom used to code stuff in Cobol... In the 80s!

Here's my try (it handles all spaces even those at the end of the string):

```sql
IF object_id('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #t
GO
CREATE TABLE #t (str VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES ('I101G2.2 OZ      001 0002200 L Y 0010000')

;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT  cast(CASE WHEN charindex(' ', t.str) = 1 THEN ' ' ELSE LEFT(str, charindex(' ', str)) END AS varchar(100)) str
    ,   0 AS startPosition
    ,   CASE WHEN charindex(' ', t.str) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE charindex(' ', t.str) END AS nextIndex
    ,   stuff(str, 1,charindex(' ', t.str)-1, '') AS strLeft 
    FROM    #t t
--  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  cast(CASE WHEN charindex(' ', t.strLeft) = 1 THEN ' ' WHEN charindex(' ', t.strleft) = 0 THEN strLeft ELSE LEFT(strLeft, charindex(' ', strLeft)) END AS varchar(100))
    ,   startPosition + nextIndex
    ,   CASE WHEN charindex(' ', t.strLeft) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE charindex(' ', t.strLeft) END
    ,   stuff(strLeft, 1,charindex(' ', t.strLeft) + CASE WHEN charindex(' ', t.strleft) <> 1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END, '')
    FROM    CTE t
    WHERE   datalength(strLeft) > 0
    )
SELECT  str, startPosition, datalength(str) AS length
FROM    cte
OPTION(maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: We are in the process of moving our production Cobol applications to .NET / SQL.  But we have to do it one piece at a time.  They are very complex and the original programmers are long gone.  The program I am converting was written in 1971!

This is exactly what I was looking for!  

Question:  What is the OPTION(maxrecursion 0) for?

Comment: As this came up as a side-note: you may use an intermediate hop (ok, maybe you'll be that lucky that you keep it ;-) using GnuCOBOL; this way you can move much more and faster and then call the native shared object for GnuCOBOL via .NET.
Also you'd be able to do SQL via preprocessors to different DBs from GnuCOBOL and then interact with it using SQL where needed.

Comment: 1971, that's awesome, i hope noone have to maintain my own code after 50 years =)
OPTION(maxrecursion 0) - This option is to handle recursive/looping CTEs (such CTE selects from itself as a UNION ALL). This option tells the server that it can make unlimited number of loops in the CTE. Without this option, the query will error if the CTE will run over 100 of times. It might not be needed in your code, but i usually always add it when writing recursive CTEs. On the other hand, it makes it really important so the code actually "finish" the loop :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact requirements here, but this is a pretty standard string split with an ordinal type of situation.

Give this a whirl:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

DECLARE @ThatsALongOne NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'I101G2.2 OZ  001 0002200 L       Y        0010000                     ';
DECLARE @WhaddaYaWant NVARCHAR(10) = ' ';

SET @ThatsALongOne+='.'
;WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT @ThatsALongOne  AS TheWholeSheBang, 
CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,@ThatsALongOne)-1  AS CI, LEN(@ThatsALongOne)  AS LEN, 
CASE WHEN LEFT(LEFT(@ThatsALongOne ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,@ThatsALongOne)),1) = @WhaddaYaWant THEN @WhaddaYaWant ELSE LEFT(@ThatsALongOne ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,@ThatsALongOne)) END AS This, 
CASE WHEN LEFT(LEFT(@ThatsALongOne ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,@ThatsALongOne)),1) = @WhaddaYaWant THEN RIGHT(@ThatsALongOne, LEN(@ThatsALongOne) -CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,@ThatsALongOne )) ELSE RIGHT(@ThatsALongOne, 1+ LEN(@ThatsALongOne) -CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,@ThatsALongOne )) END AS WhatsLeft
, 1 AS Incidence
, CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS Start
UNION ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                   
SELECT @ThatsALongOne  AS TheWholeSheBang, 
CASE WHEN LEFT(LEFT(WhatsLeft ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft)),1) = @WhaddaYaWant THEN 1 ELSE LEN(LEFT(WhatsLeft ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft))) END     AS CI, 
LEN(WhatsLeft)       AS LEN, 
CASE WHEN LEFT(LEFT(WhatsLeft ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft)),1) = @WhaddaYaWant THEN @WhaddaYaWant ELSE LEFT(WhatsLeft ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft)) END AS This, 
CASE WHEN LEFT(LEFT(WhatsLeft ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft)),1) = @WhaddaYaWant THEN RIGHT(@ThatsALongOne, LEN(WhatsLeft) -CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft )) ELSE RIGHT(WhatsLeft, 1+ LEN(WhatsLeft) -CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft )) END AS WhatsLeft
, Incidence + 1 AS Incidence
, CASE WHEN LEFT(LEFT(WhatsLeft ,CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft)),1) = @WhaddaYaWant THEN 1 ELSE CHARINDEX(@WhaddaYaWant,WhatsLeft) END
FROM cte
 WHERE WhatsLeft <> '.'
)

SELECT This AS SubString, SUM(CI) OVER (PARTITION BY cte.TheWholeSheBang ORDER BY cte.Incidence)-CI AS StartingPosition, CI AS Length
  FROM cte
```

```
SubString   StartingPosition    Length
I101G2.2    0                   8
            8                   1
OZ          9                   2
            11                  1
            12                  1
001         13                  3
..
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this in c#, you can simply walk the string in a loop. As we encounter non-space characters, we can append them to a `StringBuilder`. When we encounter a space, we would then first add the characters we've captured so far, along with their length and starting position, to a list of strings (each representing a substring), clear the `StringBuilder` for the next substring, and then add the space character and it's position and length. At the end of the loop, if our `StringBuilder` has a substring in it, add it to the list and then return the list.

One bug in your original example is that the first substring started at position `0` and had `8` characters. This means that the next substring should start at position `8`, but your example shows it starting at `9`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
public static List<string> GetParts(string input)
{
    if (input == null) return null;
    var result = new List<string>();
    if (input.Length == 0) return result;

    var currentPart = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ')
        {
            if (currentPart.Length > 0)
            {
                var part = currentPart.ToString();
                result.Add($"{part},{i - part.Length},{part.Length}");
                currentPart.Clear();
            }

            result.Add($"{{space}},{i},1");
        }
        else
        {
            currentPart.Append(input[i]);
        }
    }

    if (currentPart.Length > 0)
    {
        var part = currentPart.ToString();
        result.Add($"{part},{input.Length - part.Length - 1},{part.Length}");
    }

    return result;
}
```

And an example calling it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = 
        "I101G2.2 OZ  001 0002200 L       Y        0010000                     ";
        
    var parts = GetParts(input);
    parts.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    Console.Write("\n\nDone. Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```